# XML read Line attribute

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read a xml file for a school's project, where i need to read the informaton and after sent to the proper classes

The line:

```
 `<node_list>
  <node id="n0"/>
  <node id="n1"/>
  <node id="n2"/>
   </node_list>`
```

I want to get the n0,n1,n2 ... but i have no idea how...

This project uses the java language and DOM XML Parser libraby.

I already tried the `getAttribute("id")` and  `getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent()` but still with no results:

```
        NodeList listNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("node_list");

        for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < listNode.getLength(); temp2++) {

            Node node = listNode.item(temp2);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getNodeName());

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;

                //System.out.println("Node id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                //System.out.println("Node ID : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent().trim());

            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help u coders can give ;)

Comment: should it be : doc.getElementsByTagName("node");

Comment: i guess no

doc referes to            

      'Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();'



and when i print doc.getElementsByTagName("node") ... appear this com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@5c647e05

---

i also tried  eElement.getElementsByTagName("node")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at this line

```
Node node = listNode.item(temp2);
```

node is a `node_list` element but not `node` element.
You can directly get the `node` element list, The code is showing the following.

```
NodeList listNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("node");

    for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < listNode.getLength(); temp2++) {

        Node node = listNode.item(temp2);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getNodeName());

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) node;

            System.out.println("Node id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));

        }
    }
```

Finally, I recommend the W3school website to study XML DOM : [XML DOM Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("node_list");
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        NodeList nodeListChildNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for(int j = 0; j < nodeListChildNodes.getLength(); j++)
        {
            Node child = nodeListChildNodes.item(j);
            if("node".equals(child.getNodeName()))
            {
                System.out.println(child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to admit i'm not familiar with getChildNodes() ... I started with DOM 3 hours ago.  i'll see more about this. Once again thanks Josh all rest of the users for the answer :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Please accept my answer so I can get the points.